# How correct remove one entity from another?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I use Spring Data.
There are two entities. I want to fire an employee. 
If I fire an employee: 
 1. I will remove a position in entity Employee (it will be null)
 2. And in entity Position, I will remove the employee from a set of employees.

I checked that the "fire" method correctly remove from Position_Employees_JT table
and position and employee continue to exist in a database.

But is it the correct approach or it better to write a query (HQL or JPQL)?
What if I want to write a more sophisticated method, what language better to use?

I remove get/set and another unnecessary code.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long employeeId;

    private String firstName;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = ALL, fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_position")
    private Position position;

    public void removePosition(){
        this.position = null;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Position {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "POSITION_ID", updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    private PositionName name;

    @JoinTable(name = "Position_Employees_JT",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_POSITION", referencedColumnName = "POSITION_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_EMPLOYEE", referencedColumnName = "EMPLOYEE_ID"))
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Employee> employeeSet = new HashSet<>();

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee){
        employeeSet.add(employee);
    }

    public void removeEmployee(Employee employee){
        employeeSet.remove(employee);
    }
}
```

The "fire" method:

```
@Transactional
public Employee fireEmployee(Long id) {
    Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepository.findById(id);
    Optional<Position> position = positionRepository.findById(employee.get().getPosition().getId()); 
    position.get().removeEmployee(employee.get());
    employee.get().removePosition();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Don't you should call `employee.get().remove();`? Don't remove from the position, it's a one-to-many relationship. Only the employee actually has control.

Answer (score 0):

The comments below:

```java
@Transactional
public Employee fireEmployee(Long id) {
    Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepository.findById(id);
    Optional<Position> position = positionRepository.findById(employee.get().getPosition().getId()); 
    position.get().removeEmployee(employee.get()); //this only affects the set in the memory, will not affect the database record
    employee.get().remove(); //this will actually delete record from the database
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be having a parent-child relation between Employee and Position.
I would suggest to fetch only **employee** from db. It would fetch respective **position** as well.

```
@Transactional
public Employee fireEmployee(Long id) {
    Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepository.findById(id);
    employee.get().remove();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: My logic is to create an employee and a position. In employee service, I can hire and fire an employee. 
For fire logic:
remove a position from an employee, 
remove an employee from a set in position.

For the relation will be created a table Position_Employees_JT.
To write this case, I need to fetch an employee and remove a position. Is that all?

I don't want to remove an employee or position, only the relation between them.